# Add array values into one json object using javascript or Lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, lodash

I searched online and read up on the Lodash documentation, but could not find a quick fix to this.

Basically, I have two arrays

```
var employee = ["John", "Mary"];
var location = ["APAC", "singapore"];
```

And eventually I would like to have a Json object that look like this:

```
var obj = {
   "profile": [
    {
      "name": "John",
      "location": ["APAC","Singapore"]
    },
    {
      "name": "Mary",
      "location": ["APAC","Singapore"]
    }
   ]
}
```

Comment: why is `"Mary"` missed?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: made a correction : I looked at _.zipObject and _.castArray, but have yet to figure out how to add "profile", "name" or "location" into the object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `location` as variable name (`var location ...`) because it will conflict with [***window.location***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) object.

The solution using `Array.prototype.reduce()` function:

```js
var employee = ["John", "Mary"],
    loc = ["APAC", "Singapore"],
    result = employee.reduce(function (r, e) {
        r.profile.push({"name": e, "location": loc.slice()});
        return r;
    }, {profile: []});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This a really nice way of doing it!

Comment: `reduce` is just a waste! `map` is better!

Comment: This is really a neat way of doing it without using a for loop, thanks!

Comment: Also a quick question, why do you use loc.slice()? I dont see the difference in array if you just push loc

Comment: @hao, Javascript arrays are passed by reference, you should use `Array.prototype.slice()` to push a copy of the initial array(to avoid further modifications)

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir, wrong, `map()` will return an array, but the OP wanted the result to be an object

Comment: RomanPerekhrest look at @Turtle answer using `map`, it's perfect and yet it got downvoted!

Answer (score 3):

You could use [_.zipWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#zipWith) with lodash:

```
var employee = ["John", "Mary"];
var location = ["APAC", "singapore"];
var output = {
  profile: _.zipWith(employee, name =>  ({
    name,
    location
  }))
};

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the above you could do the following using ES2015:

```
const employees = ["John", "Mary"];
const locations = ["APAC", "singapore"];

const final = []

employees.forEach( (employee) => {
  let obj = {
    name: employee,
    location: [...locations]
  }
  final.push(obj)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and dirty solution using map and node:

```
var obj = {
  "profile": employees.map((name) => {
    return {
      "name": name,
      "location": location
    };
  })
};
```

Comment: `map` returns a new array, not changing the original!

Comment: Plus the whole `location` array should be attached to all the employees not just the one at the same index!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a simple loop will do the trick :

```
var obj = { "profile" : [] };
employee.forEach(function(e) {
    obj.profile.push({ "name": e, "location": location });
});
```

Comment: I believe the location would not work using this solution as you would get a circular object you could fix this by using the ES2015 spread operator [...location]

Comment: It works, but he needs to rename the var location as it will conflict with window.location, as mentioned in an answer before.